# PHP - Error when trying to use ceiling function on data retrieved from database

Tags: php

Below is my PHP code. I'm tying to retrieve values from a database and round them to the nearest 10 (upwards only). All the values in the database in this column are integers.

```
<?PHP
    @$Teach_ID = $_POST['txtteachID'];
    @$Class_ID = $_POST['txtclass'];
    @$BookingDate = $_POST['txtbookingdate'];
    @$BookingPeriod = $_POST['txtperiod'];

    require_once('../BookingSystem/DBconnect.php');

    $capacity = 'SELECT ClassSize FROM classes WHERE ClassID = 1';
        $result = $dbh->query($capacity);
        $result = (int)$result;
    function ceiling($number, $significance = 1)
        {
            return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
        }
    }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo ceiling($result, 10);
    }
    ?>
```

**Error Description**

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your `$result` variable, which is a `mysqli_result` object, to get its different entries.

Use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to get the values, which will end in something like this :

```
$capacity = 'SELECT ClassSize FROM classes WHERE ClassID = 1';
$result = $dbh->query($capacity);
function ceiling($number, $significance = 1)
{
    return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (ceil($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
    }
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // if ($result->num_rows > 0) { /* I think this condition is not needed anymore */
        $value = intval($row['ClassSize'], 10); // will convert the string from database to an int in base 10
        echo ceiling($value, 10); /* I suppose you wanted to use the ClassSize key since it's the one you query */
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this `$result = (int)$result;`. You have to irritate over each row and then extract the data.

Comment: That's a comment please do a complete answer :) Show us how to iterate for example, and explain more why you cannot do the `(int) $result;` :p